# how print the player who have the nearest number

Tags: python

```
score_p1 = 0
score_p2 = 0
score_p3 = 0
score_p4 = 0

p1 = int(input("Player1 please enter number(0,100): "))
p2 = int(input("Player2 please enter number(0,100): "))
p3 = int(input("Player3 please enter number(0,100): "))
p4 = int(input("Player4 please enter number(0,100): "))

if p1>=0 and p1 <= 100:
    print()
else:
    print("Player1, You should enter between 0 and 100! ")
if p2>=0 and p2 <= 100:
    print()
else:
    print("Player2, You should enter between 0 and 100! ")
if p3>=0 and p3 <= 100:
    print()
else:
    print("Player3, You should enter between 0 and 100! ")
if p4>=0 and p4 <= 100:
    print()
else:
    print("Player4, You should enter between 0 and 100! ")

all_sum = 0 
numbers = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

for number in numbers:
    all_sum += number
    average = all_sum / len(numbers)
    multi = average * 0.8
                        
minus = [abs(y-multi) for y in numbers]     
x = numbers[minus.index(min(minus))]
print("The nearest number is:", x)
```

this is a game that we have 4 players and we get number input(0,100) from all of them and calculate the average and multiply the answer to the 0.8 and the player who has the nearest number to the answer is the winner and the 3 other players are the losers (losers get -1 score).

I have problem to how print the name of the winner too not just the number and how my program auto -1 score from losers.

Comment: In the second to last line you determine already the index of the winning number in "numbers". This index relates to the number of the winning player.

Comment: Ties are definitely possible. Computing the min index and finding the player corresponding to it would just declare the first winning player the winner and implicitly scoring the other winning player(s) as a loser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code to:

```
all_sum = 0 
for number in numbers:
    all_sum += number
average = all_sum / len(numbers)  # this part should be outside of the loop
multi = average * 0.8

# compute the min
minus = [abs(y-multi) for y in numbers]
# index of the min value (of not tie!)
idx = minus.index(min(minus))

print(f"The nearest number is: {numbers[idx]}")
print(f'The winner is Player {idx+1}')
```

Another option using a dictionary, which enables you to use custom names:

```
from statistics import mean

players = {'p1': p1, 'p2': p2, 'Nikolat': p3, 'p4': p4}
multi = mean(players.values())

winner = min(players, key=lambda k: abs(players[k]-multi))

print(f'The winner is {winner} with a value of {players[winner]}')
```

Output (with 10, 20, 30, 80 as inputs):

```
The winner is Nikolat with a value of 30
```

Handling ties:

```
MIN = min(players.values(), key=lambda v: abs(v-multi))
winners = [p for p in players if players[p] == MIN]

if len(winner)>1:
    print(f'The winners are {" and ".join(winners)} with a value of {MIN}')
else:
    print(f'The winner is {winner} with a value of {MIN}')
```

Comment: thank you! it was perfect but how auto -1 score from loosers? and i want when someone reached to -5 score he get kickout how i can do that too?

Comment: There is only in single turn in your current code; you would need an extra loop to repeat the game which would handle the players and kick them if needed. That's quite a different question ;)